# Can I get Protractor/Jasmine to hit a breakpoint when an element locator fails to find its target?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Every time a Protractor element locator fails, it prints an error and continues down a horrible path of endless cascading failures in my spec and suite. Every test that follows depends on the element locator finding its element, and depends on the current spec passing.

I would like to keep the web page under test open while I use the console. The goal is to debug the current state of the page and investigate why the element locator may have failed to find its target.

I'm not too concerned about failing the entire suite and exiting on the first spec failure (I've seen other answers on --fail-fast and stopping on first spec failure.) This is not the approach I would like to take. I want to set a breakpoint, and inspect the environment while the page is running.

Maybe there's something like a Jasmine option for `doThisOnFailure: () => { debugger }`, which would work for me I think.

I really do not like the solution of using a spec reporter to execute during `afterEach` and check the failed spec count on the Jasmine environment for the entire spec function. I want to immediately know when an element locator has failed and immediately break as soon as it has failed.

Maybe something really gross would work `$('element').click().catch(() => { debugger })`.

**EDIT:** Please, note that I am asking about breaking in a spec, not breaking at the end of the spec.

```
it('should execute deadly code', function () {
    p.navigation.openStorageConfigTab()
    $$('.bad-selector').get(0).click() /* IMPORTANT: I want to break here */
    p.volume.navigateTo()
})

it('should not execute this spec', function () {
    $$('.bad-selector').get(0).click()
})
```

And the output

```
  ✗ should execute deadly code
    - Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .bad-selector)
  ✗ should not execute this spec
    - Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, .bad-selector)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you the approach I use, and I hope you can take it from here

Overall approach is to wait until until you type `close/` command in browser url:

```
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
await browser.wait(
  async () => {
    let url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
    return url.includes('close/');
  },
  5 * 60 * 1000,
  'Keep-alive timeout reached, closing the session...'
);
```

The question is when you want to call it. I use the advantage of `onComplete` callback function in config file. When it's called, the browser is still available. So once all tests are completed, it doesn't exit for 5 minutes unless I submit `close/` to the url field. Obviously that can be conditional, by adding something like `if (DEBUG === true)`

A downside of this setup is it's called when all tests are completed, and it's possible your spec has navigated away from the page where there was error. So what you can also do is to use advantage of jasmine reporter (if you use jasmine). Roughly, you just need to add this to your `onPrepare` func:

```
jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
    jasmineStarted: function(suiteInfo) {},
    suiteStarted: function(result) {},
    specStarted: function(result) {},
    specDone: async function(spec) {
        if (spec.status === 'failed') {
            await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
            await browser.wait(
                async () => {
                    let url = await browser.getCurrentUrl();
                    return url.includes('close/');
                },
                5 * 60 * 1000,
                'Keep-alive timeout reached, closing the session...'
            );
            await browser.close();
            process.exit(35);
        }
    },
    suiteDone: function(result) {},
    jasmineDone: function(result) {},
});
```

So if any `it` block has `failed` status, then it'll stop. BUT, I have not tested it, I'll leave it up to you. And second, I didn't think about what will happen to the rest of queued specs since you're redirected to non existing url `close/`, but I believe it'll still work for you. Worst case scenario, you can play around and make it continue or close the browser instance, as long as you understood the concept

P.S.
I modified the code to close the browser when you type `close/`, by adding

```
await browser.close();
process.exit(35);
```

I tested this code with the following scenarios:

- happy path: all 5 `it` are successful
- first element finder of second `it` block fails
- second element finder of second `it` block fails

All passed. The code works as expected

Comment: it is. What happens when protractor fails to find an element, if marks `it` block as failed, throws an error, exits this particular step (`it`), and before the next one started, `specDone` function is called. Don't let the name `spec` confuse you - `spec === it` (not spec file) and `suite === describe`. Give it a try first and let me know what errors you encounter

Comment: worst case scenario, place it in `afterEach` section and check if `it` status is failed. Though you'll have to duplicate the code to each spec file

Comment: You'll be surprised if you try

Comment: well, one correction, unless you wrap every `$(...)` in `try/catch` this will work

Comment: @activedecay I just tested the code locally, all works. I improved the code to exit protractor when you type `close/`

Comment: Yes, it works! And it was surprising to see that if the first element finder dies, then the next specs are not executed. The element finder that has the bad selector gets executed and I suppose it throws an exception. I was confused because I had hoped that this bad code path would be reachable by hitting a breakpoint. It seems like we have to just let the exception through, and use your solution to halt the test progress.